# Conocer el tamaño de un array pasado por parámetro en c++

Tags: c++, array

Buenas,

tengo el siguiente código en c++:

```
int main()
{
    int firstarray[] = {5, 10, 15};
    int secondarray[] = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10};

    int tamanoArray = sizeof(firstarray)/sizeof(*firstarray);


    cout << "El tamano del array es: " << tamanoArray << endl;

    printarray(firstarray);
    printarray(secondarray);


    return 0;

}

void printarray (int arg[]) { //array as parameters
    int tamanoArray = sizeof(arg)/sizeof(*arg);


    cout << "El tamano del array es: " << tamanoArray << endl;


    for (int n=0; n<tamanoArray; n++)
        cout << arg[n] << ' ';

    cout << endl;
}
```

El detalle es que dentro de la función printarray el tamaño de mi array me da como resultado un número 1, mientras que dentro del main obtengo el resultado correcto; acaso no esta recibiendo una copia del array en mi función, por q ocurre esto?

Comment: No se puede obtener el tamaño de un array si lo pasas como un puntero ya que lo que mediria sería el tamaño del puntero

Comment: Esta pregunta esta respondida en http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108313/how-do-i-find-the-length-of-an-array

Answer (score 2):

```
void printarray (int arg[])
```

Imagínate que yo cojo tu código, le modifico algunos parámetros y te enseño únicamente la línea anterior. ¿Eres capaz de conocer el tamaño del arreglo? obviamente no y, por supuesto, el compilador tampoco será capaz.

Aunque el arreglo lo estés declarando prácticamente igual el compilador no hace magia, no sabe qué es lo que le vas a pasar a esa función cada vez que la llames. El compilador va a tratar ´arg` como un puntero:

```
void printarray (int *arg)
```

De hecho te daría igual poner el tamaño del arreglo en la cabecera de la función:

```
void func1(int *arg)
{
    std::cout << sizeof(arg) * sizeof(int) << '\n';
}

void func2(int arg[])
{
    std::cout << sizeof(arg) * sizeof(int) << '\n';
}

void func3(int arg[5])
{
    std::cout << sizeof(arg) * sizeof(int) << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    int arg[5];
    func1(arg);
    func2(arg);
    func3(arg);
}
```

Podrás verificar que las tres funciones imprimen exactamente el mismo valor. En mi caso 32 (bits).

Una diferencia sustancial la puedes encontrar al trabajar con arreglos de dos o más dimensiones. En este caso es necesario especificar todas las dimensiones menos la primera y el motivo es que el compilador necesita esa información para calcular correctamente los saltos.

Las siguientes cabeceras son equivalentes:

```
void func( int arg[][6] );
void func( int arg[5][6] );
```

Es por este motivo que las funciones de la librería estándar que trabajan con arreglos requieren al menos dos argumentos: el arreglo y el tamaño del mismo.

Este problema lo puedes evitar si usas `std::array` (para arreglos de tamaño fijo) o `std::vector` (para arreglos de tamaño variable) en vez de arreglos crudos:

```
std::array<3,int> firstArray = { 5, 10, 15 };

// número de elementos del array
std::cout << firstArray.size();
```

La gran ventaja de usar `std::array` es que su rendimiento es equivalente al de los arreglos crudos mientras que su mayor desventaja es que el tamaño del array lo acompaña en la declaración, lo cual obliga, a la hora de generalizar algoritmos, a usar iteradores:

```
template<class Iterador>
void PrintArray(Iterador it, Iterador end)
{
  for( ; it != end; ++it )
    std::cout << *it << '\n';
}

std::array<3,int> firstArray = { 5, 10, 15 };
PrintArray(firstArray.begin(),firstArray.end());

std::array<5,int> secondArray = { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 };
PrintArray(secondArray .begin(),secondArray .end());
```

Salida:

```
5
10
15
2
4
6
8
10
```

Con `std::vector` no es necesario recurrir a los iteradores, aunque una vez te acostumbras son bastante cómodos.

```
template<class Iterador>
void PrintArray(Iterador it, Iterador end)
{
  for( ; it != end; ++it )
    std::cout << *it << '\n';
}

void PrintVector(const std::vector<int>& v)
{
  for(size_t i=0; i<v.size(); ++i)
    std::cout << v[i] << '\n';
}

std::vector<int> firstArray = { 5, 10, 15 };
PrintArray(firstArray.begin(),firstArray.end());
PrintVector(firstArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, la función no está recibiendo una copia del array. Está recibiendo un puntero al primer elemento del mismo.

Por lo que en la función al estar intentando conseguir el tamaño del array con esa división en realidad lo que haces es una división del tamaño de un puntero con el tamaño de un int, que en una arquitectura de 32b es 1.

La solución que dan de usar contenedores c++ sería la ideal para no tener que lidiar con punteros.

Si quieres seguir usando arrays de C no te queda otra que pasar el tamaño del array a la función como parámetro extra.

```
void printarray ( int arg[], int tamano )
```

así en el main tendrás que calcular el tamaño de cada array antes de pasarlo:

```
int tamanoArray = sizeof( firstarray )/sizeof( *firstarray );
printarray( firstarray, tamanoArray );
tamanoArray = sizeof( secondarray )/sizeof( *secondarray );
printarray( secondarray, tamanoArray );
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto es una traducción de https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108313/how-do-i-find-the-length-of-an-array

> Si te refieres a una matriz de estilo C, entonces puedes hacer algo
>   como:
>
> ```
> Int a [7];
> Std :: cout << "Longitud del arreglo =" << (sizeof (a) / sizeof (* a)) << std :: endl;
> ```
>
> Esto no funciona en punteros, aunque, es decir, no funcionará para
>   ninguno de los siguientes:
>
> ```
> Int * p = new int [7];
> Std :: cout << "Longitud del array =" << (sizeof (p) / sizeof (* p)) << std :: endl;
> ```
>
> o:
>
> ```
> Void func (int * p)
> {
>     Std :: cout << "Longitud del array =" << (sizeof (p) / sizeof (* p)) << std :: endl;
> }
>
> Int a [7];
> Func (a);
> ```
>
> En C + +, si quieres este tipo de comportamiento, entonces deberías
>   usar una clase container; Probablemente `std :: vector`.